# find minimum value of p1+p2+p3+p4 where pi represents position of substituent and functional group in iupac name p1-bromo-p2-chloro-pent-p3-en-p4-one

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have tried all I could for this question the answer I reached is 7 as in the attached pic but the book says 6[image: just a C is missing after the double bonded 4 th Carbon]

Comment: Please rotate your image.

Comment: Voting to close. Needs more details and the structure in image is not the same as that in title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put Br and Cl in the same carbon. In 1-bromo-1-chloro-pent-1-en-3-one , p1+p2+p3+p4 is equal to 6. I think this is the smallest p1+p2+p3+p4 which can be reached according to IUPAC rules of nomenclature.